# How to hide one item from drawer android

Tags: android

I am a new application developer.I use in my app drawer it has many options for the user.But sometimes I want to set a condition and hide an element from it.Sorry to ask the question again, but I tried to work on our previous posts and didn't work with me.

This is my code:

```
   NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Profile) {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, UserProfile.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_Politics) {

            Intent i = new Intent(this, Ploysity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } 

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;

    }
```

So for example I want to hide nav_Politics how I can hide  it?

Comment: Do you want to remove nav_Politics list item or hide the drawer containing list?

Comment: hide the drawer containing list @gpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this snippet of code:

```
mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);

mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.RIGHT, false);
```

Use Gravity.LEFT or GravityCompat.START to move the left drawer. Use Gravity.RIGHT or GravityCompat.END for the right.
false disable drawer closing animation.